# Tener instaladas versiones en android-studio por encima de las del proyecto

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo en Android Studio instaladas las versiones de Api Android 24 a 26 , el tema que tengo un proyecto entre manos que va desde 14 como mínima a 24, la pregunta es.

> ¿Hay que seleccionar una API en concreto o ya Android Studio coge la
>   que mejor se adapte?

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Tengo en Android Studio instaladas las versiones de Api Android 24 a
>   26 ,

Es decir que tienes instaladas estas APIS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> tengo un proyecto entre manos que va desde 14 como mínima a 24

Es decir tienes definido en tu proyecto dentro de tu `build.gradle`:

```
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 24
```

> ¿Hay que seleccionar una en concreto o ya Android Studio coge la que
>   mejor se adapte?

**En realidad tu determinas la configuración de tu proyecto en tu archivo `build.gradle`**, en este caso definir un [**minSdkVersion**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#min) indica desde que API tu aplicación es soportada y [**targetSdkVersion**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target) con que API tu aplicación es compilada, y debe estar instalada (ver imagen anterior).

En este caso se determina que tu aplicación solo puede funcionar desde android 4.0 ya que tienes definido `minSdkVersion 14` hasta cualquier versión, ya que no defines un [**maxSdkVersion**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#max).

- Si tu aplicación se sube a Google Play no aparecerá a usuarios que tengan sistema operativo menor a Android 4.0 (API 14).
- Si no defines indicas [**minSdkVersion**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target) ni [**maxSdkVersion**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#max) indicas que tu aplicación puede ser usada por cualquier sistema operativo.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio compila el proyecto de aplicación (o librería) según la información contenida en el archivo *build.gradle* de tu proyecto. Ahí es donde le dices como quieres que construya tu app a nivel compatibilidades.

Veamos un Ejemplo de un archivo build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.brightcrowns.app.miapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26

...
```

- *compileSdkVersion 26* : indica que se compile con la versión de SDK 26. Esta es la versión de SDK debes tener instalada.
- *minSdkVersion 15* : indica que la app debe poder correr mínimamente en Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0–4.0.5)
- *targetSdkVersion 26* : indica que debe tener compatibilidad hasta la versión Oreo (8.0)

Es decir que la app generada contendrá compatibilidad suficiente para ejecutar en toda la gama de Android desde la versión 4.0 a la 8.0 (mientras mas grande la gama, mas grande el apk generado, y tambien hay que tener en cuenta algunos detalles de compatibilidad a la hora de programarlo).

Espero haber respondido tu pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. Me parece curioso que afecte al tamaño pero es comprensible porque añadirá otras librerías para hacerlo compatible , con las otras apis.